# Mapbox background layer click event not working

Tags: events, background, click, mapbox, layer

I'm trying to set up a click event on a transparent background layer in Mapbox. Here is a code snippet:

```
    map.on('load', function () {
          map.addLayer({
            id: 'transparent',
            type: 'background',
            interactive: true,
            paint: {
              'background-color': '#dedede',
              'background-opacity': 0
            }
    
          })
    }
    
    //This doesn't print Hello World to the console
    map.on('click', 'transparent', function () {
      console.log('Hello World')
    })
```

Calling the same event on a symbol layer works without a problem. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/map/#map#on: "Event will only be triggered if its location is within a visible feature in this layer". There are no features in a background layer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Layers specify the Source's styles. The type of layer is specified by the 'type' property and must be one of background, fill, line, symbol, raster, circle, fill-extrusion, heatmap, hillshade.

Except for layers of the background type, each layer needs to refer to a source.

Layers take the data that they get from a source, optionally filter features, and then define how those features are styled.

I recommend adding an event on Map instead like:

```
map.on('click', function (e) {
//code
});
```

Example:

```
https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/mouse-position/
```

How to add background layer:

```
https://bl.ocks.org/stevage/a09dcbd11fb24b20033f2d3f6ab01374
```